# MYSQL query start time and end time

Tags: php, mysql

How would I display with mysql the start time and end time from the current week (starting Sunday) with an interval of 2 weeks?

Example:

```
id  starttime            endtime
2   2015-02-06 09:17:25  2015-02-06 12:17:25
2   2015-01-15 09:17:25  2015-01-15 12:17:25
```

The **result** would just display the first field because it is a "new week" and the first field is from a previous month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`YEARWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function to match the time in the table with the current week.

```
SELECT id, starttime, endtime
FROM yourTable
WHERE YEARWEEK(starttime, 0) IN (YEARWEEK(NOW(), 0), YEARWEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 0))
```

The `0` argument means the week starts on Sunday.

Comment: I've added a test for this week and next week.